# Add delay between two functions in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two functions and I need a forced delay between those two consecutive function calls. That is to say,

```
a // call func a
delay(100) // delay for 100 ms
b // call func b
```

Is there anyway to do so?

Edit: tried

```
  a();
  console.log("a");
  setTimeout(b(), 1000);
  console.log("b");
```

Comment: Probably `setTimeout`?

Comment: `a(); setTimeout(() => {console.log("delayed");  b()}, 100);`??

Comment: retrying........

Comment: Do you want to finish the execution of `a()` then wait for 100ms and then call `b()`??

Comment: You know that using `setTimeout` is a bad practice...

Comment: @Oleksii Why is inherently bad?

Comment: @AshishRanjan sort of

Comment: Why are you trying to use timeout/delay? Why do you need a timeout for setState after POST request? Maybe there are some other way to achive your goal.

Comment: @Oleksii `setTimeout` is not automatically bad practice.. source? there are tons of times where it's needed

Comment: The problem is, you're executing `b` while invoking `setTimeout`. It should be `setTimeout(b, 1000)` instead of `setTimeout(b(), 1000)`

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is to make use of [`setTimeout function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) to call `b` after calling `a`

```
a() // call func a
setTimeout(b, 100) // delay for 100 ms
```

if you need to keep `b` function bound to the current scope, use:

```
setTimeout(() => b(), 100) // () => {} functions are always bound to the current scope
```

Comment: @IsaacFerreira @Li357 the benefit to wraping in an inline function is that the proper `this` is kept without explicit binding

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I tried this and that does not seem to be working. I edited the question to show what I did, could you take a look?

Comment: In this case, `this` is useless, once it's just a calling.

Comment: @Li357 it's not my answer and I'm one of the two upvotes on Isaac Ferreira's comment. I understand that it's not necessary here, but if the OP doesn't even know how to use a timeout, they probably would have no idea what to do when they use this on a function that DOES need scope and it comes out wrong

Comment: setTimeout expects the first parameter as the function that it will execute and hence `setTimeout(b(), 1000);` isn't the correct syntax

Comment: one thing is there, when you say 100ms delay. It cannot be 100ms delay always. It can be mimimum 100ms delay. As you dont know whether your call stack is free after 200ms

Answer (score 3):

With new ES6, you can even make it more cleaner and look like sequential,

```js
function delay(ms) {
   return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, ms);
   })
}

async function doItHere() {
   console.log('a', Date.now());
   await delay(5000);
   console.log('b', Date.now())
}

doItHere();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
a() // First call function a
```

Then call function b in **setTimeout** function.

**es5**:

```
setTimeout(function() {b()},100);
```

**es6**:

```
setTimeout(()=> {b()},100);
```

Comment: No. Unless `b` returns a function, this will just immediately call `b`